# How to pass value into CGFloat

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a the following code which is Cocoa Touch class, which draws a simple pie chart, and with the value `CGFloat` I can adjust the image to show the correct information.

How can I pass a value for example from a slider in the main view controler.swift to it, instead of having it fixed?

```
public class PieChart : NSObject {



public class func drawCanvas1(ratio ratio: CGFloat = 0.75) {

    //// Variable Declarations
    let expression: CGFloat = 90 + ratio * 360


    let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: -0, width: 112, height: 112))
    UIColor.blackColor().setFill()
    ovalPath.fill()



    let oval2Rect = CGRect(x: 4, y: 4, width: 104, height: 104)
    let oval2Path = UIBezierPath()
    oval2Path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: oval2Rect.midX, y: oval2Rect.midY), radius: oval2Rect.width / 2, startAngle: -expression * CGFloat(M_PI)/180, endAngle: -90 * CGFloat(M_PI)/180, clockwise: true)
    oval2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: oval2Rect.midX, y: oval2Rect.midY))
    oval2Path.closePath()

    UIColor.redColor().setFill()
    oval2Path.fill()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hook up your `UISlider` to a `UIControlEventValueChanged` function, similar to what you would do with a `UIButton`.  This will get called when the value on your slider changes, and you can take the `value` property of the slider at that point and pass it into `drawCanvas1`.  As long as you pass a value in, the default 0.75 will be ignored.

Comment: Like this? import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 
    (at)IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!
    

    (at)IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider) {
        
        let selectedValue = Float(sender.value)
        
        drawCanvas1 = selectedValue
        
        
    }